# What's the best placement for "select all" option in multiple filer component?

Tags: filter, multi-selection

While researching I found two main ways of placing the "Select all" option. One usually appears in the top right corner and another one (used i.e. by Microsoft it seems) is adding a Select all option on top of all filtering options. What's the difference from the user perspective and which one is the best practice?

[image: select all option on the top of filtering options]
[image: select all on top right corner]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Select all checkbox**

- More common, more modern IMO
- Also gives the user the information if only some checkboxes are checked or all (indeterminate state vs checked state)
- My choice usually

Just make sure it stands out more from the other checkboxes (e.g. line below, different background)

Comment: thanks! I will move on with your suggestion